# Failing to parse date in Logstash with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, logstash, epoch

I have a hard coded date of '1900-01-01 00:00:00' in a logging template and am getting this output.
 `"reason"=>"failed to parse date field [1900-01-01 00:00:00] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"date_time_parse_exception", "reason"=>"Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"}}}}}}`

I understand `[strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]` is complaining about the epoch time so I set the hard coded date to be `1970-01-01 00:00:00` but it is still complaining with the same error `"reason"=>"failed to parse date field [1970-01-01 00:00:00] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"date_time_parse_exception", "reason"=>"Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"}}}}}}`

I have the date set as after 1970, shouldn't this work? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve this. My hard coded date was simply missing the "T" in the middle of the date and time so it should have been "1970-01-01T00:00:00" instead of "1970-01-01 00:00:00".